# Drag and Drop Datatable inside a row Expasion Primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Drag and drop from a datatable inside a row expasion doesn't work. I can't reference to a child datatable
My xhtml is like this:

```
<h:form id="form">

 <p:datatable id="dt1">
      ....
      <p:rowExpansion>
           <p:datatable id="dt2"> 
                 (datasource of drag and drop)
            <p:datatable>
     </p:rowExpansion>
 </p:datatable>

   <p:datatable>
          (Target)
    </p:datatable>
    <p:droppable datasource=":form:dt1:0:dt2">
         <p:ajax/>
    </p:droppable>
```

I got a exception in ajax event: ":form:datatable1:0:datatable2 can't be reference"

I tried a lot.

Please I need your help.

> Primefaces 4.0 - Tomcat 7 - Hibernate 4 - Spring Framework - Maven

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think u need only put the last id for datasource.

```
<p:droppable datasource="dt2">
     <p:ajax/>
</p:droppable>
```